# In Julia how to read a scanned multipage PDF and convert to image for OCR

Tags: pdf, julia, ocr

In Julia how to read a scanned multipage PDF and convert to image for OCR.

I am using Julia v1.8 on windows OS.

Comment: did you solve this problem by any chance?